# Dual shaft servo motors? Do they have another name?

Tags: servo

I am trying to find a servo motor where the shaft protrudes through the other side however I haven't been able to find much online. I am wondering if I have the term right though. Am i right searching for "dual shaft servo" or would they be under another name?

Comment: Try with double shaft motor. Servo motor is a complete package where the other shaft end is already occupied with encoder/brake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try with the search phrase "double shaft servo motor". You will find that they are made. Below picture is one such unit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Motor itself is not servo. Searxh for specifictype of motor, like "dual shaft brushless motor".